What incentivizes governments to address problems the public is ignorant about, such as superbacteria or open DNS servers?
Before I started researching politics, I assumed that what incentivizes governments to solve problems is democracy. However, the deeper I dive into politics, it seems to me more and more that's not the case. It seems to me that governments excel at solving some problems that the public is incredibly ignorant about. My observations are:

The average person is incredibly ignorant about superbacteria, not even knowing where most antibiotics go today (Around 70% of antibiotics today is used in the egg industry, but the average person doesn't know that.).
The average person doesn't realize that open DNS servers (that respond to requests from all IP addresses, rather than just the IP addresses they are supposed to respond to) can easily be used by hackers to amplify denial-of-service attacks, since DNS servers sometimes respond with large responses to short queries (that fit in one UDP packet).
Yet, almost every country has laws governing the use of antibiotics in the egg industry, and almost every country has laws that says that ISPs must not set up their DNS servers so that they can be used to massively amplify denial-of-service attacks.

So, what incentivizes governments to address the problems of superbacteria and of open DNS servers? The possibility of being voted out of the office clearly isn't, since the public is ignorant about those problems.

"almost every country has laws that says that ISPs must not set up their DNS servers so that they can be used to massively amplify denial-of-service attacks" Citation needed, as they say. Yes, almost every country has laws that says that people shouldn't abuse computer systems (e.g. perform denial-of-service attacks). Some countries require some security measures to be taken (e.g. to protect personal data as in GDPR or sensitive infrastructure), but I doubt very much there is any law or even government-level decision that says "you cannot set up an open DNS server".

This is more often enforced by ISPs/web hosts on their customers, recursively, not because there is a law on that, but because their upstreams or peers will block all of their traffic if they do, and because they don't like being the targets themselves.

I've never heard of any laws like that about DNS servers. It's just an industry-wide "best practice".

The average person is incredibly ignorant about superbacteria, not even knowing where most antibiotics go to today (Around 70% of antibiotics today is used in the egg industry, but the average person doesn't know that.). What's the source for this claim? I find instead this: About 70 percent of medically important antibiotics sold in the U.S. are for animals. https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/to-fight-antimicrobial-resistance-start-with-farm-animals/

Government officials and outside policymakers present lawmakers with policies to address problems that lawmakers can understand.

Should we pass legislation that impairs the ability of hackers to screw up computer systems connected to the Internet?

Should we pass legislation the discourage plagues that can't be stopped with modern medicines from emerging and spreading?


Lawmakers, if they agree that preventing a bad outcome is a good idea, and if they trust the experts proposing the legislation to know how to stop it (which is particularly likely in the case of non-partisan scientific and engineering type problems), will then pass legislation which the experts have told them will deal with a problem that they can understand.
The legislators insert democratic input into their decisions by serving as proxies for what society considers bad v. good outcomes, whether it is worth doing something about, and whether the experts in question are trustworthy.
For example, some lawmakers might feel that preventing defects in contraceptives that cause unplanned pregnancies is an important thing to solve, while others might feel that this is not something that the government should take action to solve. But far more lawmakers might feel that preventing all life on Earth from being wiped out by an incoming asteroid or comet with a one time expenditure of $100 million was worth it.
It is routinely the case that people outside the legislature and outside the constituency of individual legislators come to legislators and propose legislation. Some of this comes from special interests, but plenty of it comes from government officials and experts in highly technical aspects of how our society works. Too few individual legislators are creative or smart enough (i.e. knowledgable enough about the relevant subject matter in enough depth to identify the problems and propose good solutions to them) for the process to work any other way.
The other democratic incentive is that the politicians in office when it happens are routinely blamed whenever anything major goes wrong in society (or are blamed for how bad the consequences of that event were), from volcanic eruptions to earthquakes to wildfires to inflation to gasoline prices, whether they actually had any influence or control on whether the thing that went wrong happened, or how bad it was.
So, when legislators actually can prevent something major from going wrong they usually leap at the chance to fix it.
Of course, this is only unless they are sure that they won't be in power when it happens, because the time when the bad thing will happen, if it ever does, is before they have any realistic chance of being voting into office and controlling the government. This exception is because politicians tend to selfishly ignore the general good when it conflicts with their political prospects.

are creative or smart enough could be reworded to "have the specialized expertise required".  i.e. a politician might be very smart and creative, including on other scientific/technical fields, but without the knowledge of that particular domain.  Some of the better lawmakers also accumulate domain knowledge, either themselves or through their staff.  For example, Oregon Senator Ron Wyden is fairly active on cybersecurity fronts and I am pretty sure the Risky Business podcast folk have said he does have some clues about it.

I'd add that, while the general public may not know about a given issue, if it's found out when something goes wrong that you, the public official, was told by someone that it was an issue and that you didn't do anything about it, that looks dramatically worse. The difference between, say, having Boeing door plugs fall off mid flight, and it being found out that someone told you that Boeing door plugs were not being installed correctly, and then you didn't do something to stop it because "Nobody else votes to express their opinion about Boeing door plug installations," is significant.

In other words: Lobbyism. The good kind.

@MichaelBorgwardt Really, "outside policymakers", "special interests", "experts" are lobbies. This answer just shows why lobbying is actually kind of important for democracy. Lobbies are knowledgeable and are laser-focused on one issue, whereas lawmakers don't generally have specialised knowledge and have to balance a whole range of issues. Lobbies have a negative connotation, but there are plenty of good and very useful lobbies.

I think the question is based on a narrow definition of democracy - voters deciding about the issues (via electing politicians or directly in referendums.) In reality, voters are unaware of most of the issues, and where they are aware of them - they are usually too ignorant to understand all the nuances. Indeed, few voters read hundreds pages of every legislation that their elected representatives are voting on, and even if they read it - few voters have the necessary legal, economical and other technical background to understand the legislation.
In other words, democracy is about electing qualified representatives to take care of legislation - not unlike hiring a lawyer to handle divorce, a real estate agent to mediate a house purchase, or an accountant to file a tax return - one can do it oneself, but a qualified professional does it better.
Remarks

Good discussion of the voters' unavoidable ignorance can be found in Michael Huemer's essay In Praise of Passivity (his rather logical conclusion is that abstention is the only moral attitude towards democratic process):


Political actors, including voters, activists, and leaders, are often ignorant of basic facts relevant to policy
choices. Even experts have little understanding of the working of society and little ability to predict future
outcomes. Only the most simple and uncontroversial political claims can be counted on. This is partly
because political knowledge is very difficult to attain, and partly because individuals are not sufficiently
motivated to attain it. As a result, the best advice for political actors is very often to simply stop trying to
solve social problems, since interventions not based on precise understanding are likely to do more harm
than good.


As a spectacular example of how a well-designed policy may work in a situation that neither voters, nor even-policy-makers had foreseen one can cite the discovery of AIDS: the Center for disease control and prevention (CDC) routinely collects data on various diseases, e.g., in its Morbidity and mortality weekly report. A few cases of rare disease occurring on the national scale in the same time in patients with similar profiles were too improbable to be an accident, and triggered a thorough investigation. The result was discovery of a medical condition with specific symptoms and risk factors, which was subsequently called AIDS. Only a few years later it was determined that it was caused by a previously unknown infectious agent, HIV virus, which might had existed in human population for decades or even a hundred of years. The policy here includes the existence of a government body (CDC), which carries out regular surveillance and investigates all suspicious cases.


"democracy is about ..." -- more specifically, "representative democracy is about" this.

@Barmar that's correct. The reasoning in this answer is one of the arguments against direct democracy.

Intrinsic vs. Extrinsic Motivations
It's easy to imagine that voter turnout (aka 'keeping your job') is a primary motivation for those seeking elected office - an extrinsic motivation. To the extent that this is true, the lack of knowledge of the avoided harms limits (if not entirely eliminates) the praise and support that elected officials would otherwise require.
The opposite is not true, however, of the consequences of failure.  No one will praise them for avoiding harms they never knew they were at risk of suffering. Virtually everyone will blame them, however, for harms that actually manifest (fairly or not, more often not).  Negative reinforcement isn't effective by itself, but a crisis draws scorn and demands for change, eroding incumbency advantages.
To stop the analysis here, however, presents a grossly distorted model of people who seek elected office, and leaves entirely out the vast majority of government personnel whose actions lead to effective avoidance of harms such as this.
Intrinsic motivations involve intangibles that are personal to the individual who holds them. They vary person to person and they can't be granted by anyone else. Public sector work is often for lower pay, comes with scorn and ridicule, and so those who do this work often have opportunities to improve their extrinsic rewards by leaving for the private sector. And yet, they don't.
Even where extrinsic motivators are seen to favor public sector work they are found to also be correlating powerfully with intrinsic motivators, as well. The concept of Public Service Motivation (PSM) is a subject of regular study, and is summed by the authors of a metastudy of the research:

...instead of physical and material incentives and conditions beyond personal control, stronger individual-based determinants are privileged, as symbolic and identity-based notions of contribution, respect, and recognition, altogether reflecting the inherent sense of value...

Running for office is not for the feint of heart, and only 'pays off' if one is successful.  At every level of government/public service, there is selection pressure against extrinsic motivators relative to similar work in the public sector.
This produces a natural selection effect that raises the prominence of intrinsic motivation in that population.
Elected officials and professional bureaucrats alike are citizens of their respective jurisdictions and therefore have stakes in the wellfare and prosperity of the same. Even if the general public will never know the harms that were avoided as a result of their actions, they know. They are able to then contextualize their actions in a context that makes meaning for them and from that meaning they can derive intrinsic value.
The UNDP offers categorization of the kinds of people who self-select into this line of work that I find to resonate with my own experience in the non-profit sector and as a policy scholar:

"Samaritans" defined by service to individuals in need;
"Communitarians" defined by activism for groups;
"Patriots" defined by valuing service to one's country; and
"Humanitarians" defined by service to the broader interests of humanity, broadly construed.

From the same:

In reality, motivation among frontline public sector officials varies across space and time. Assuming that all public service officials possess sufficient intrinsic motivation to serve the public good may be naive. ... However, intrinsically motivated public service workers do exist. In 2008, the International Civil Service Commission surveyed 15,000 UN Common System Staff and found that most employees joined the UN because of opportunities to use their skills to serve a good cause.

Just as it's naive to assume all public sector workers are sufficiently intrinsically motivated, it's equally foolish to assume that anyone only has one set of motivations. People do their jobs for all sorts of reasons, intrinsic and extrinsic, simultaneously.  They excel at their jobs for similar reasons.
But where you find a lack of extrinsic motivators, you also find the strong implication that intrinsic motivators must be gaining larger portions of that balance.
Self-interest is a complex thing. Even government officials whose behavior you find reprehensible are often motivated by a desire to do good in the world - the issue between you is a differing opinion about what is good.

A lot of those decisions can be taken by agencies (e.g. the FAA or FDA in the US) or lower-level department workers quite independently of cabinet-level government members, by people who are not elected at all, will most likely not change when the administration switches from one party to the other, and are just doing their job.
Their job is usually defined by broad frameworks which have been defined by the legislator (or sometimes the executive), which define not only the limits of what they can and cannot do, but also what they should do.
For instance, if the FAA says "planes of this type must be grounded until we can determine a fix for this or that issue", they're just doing their job, and I don't think there's any elected official which participates in this decision. It is the FAA's mandate to keep air travel safe, and their have a number of rights attached to that.
If they didn't do their job, they may be held liable for their failings (though government employees usually have quite broad protections).
It can become an actual political issue (involving government and/or legislators) when:

They need a lot of money, beyond the existing budget
It's not within their mandate (they're not allowed to do it, usually)
It's controversial (it would unduly infringe on the rights of others)
It's actually pushed by the executive or lawmakers for whatever reason, rather than by the agency/department itself
Or on the contrary, there is pushback from the executive or lawmakers (usually under the pressure of lobbies, sometimes whatever fraction of the electorate they want to favour).


While this should be how it works, recent SCOTUS decisions seem to be putting limits on agency authority. E.g. EPA's ability to decide what falls under laws like the Clean Water Act.

Ultimately, "government" isn't a thing. It's a bunch of people with varying priorities, united into institutions with existing rules and structures.
What motivates people to solve a problem? One of 3 things:

Intrinsic motivation. They want the problem fixed. Yes, people are just lazy stupid apes for most part. But some of them some of the times can have wisdom, foresight and good intentions. If you are aware of DNS problem, you just may want it fixed because you don't want DNS broken because it's bad.
Note that whether the public is aware isn't important here. What's important is whether the technical underlings you hire to actually run things are aware. I'm sure no president ever was aware of what DNS is. But they have a secretary for this that an another, who has an undersecretary, who has 10 aides, who also talk to staffers at agencies. Eventually they get info from actual IT experts.
Does this work well all the time for all the issues? Um. Look at reality. Of course it doesn't. Does it work for some stuff sometimes? Yes it does.
Some people in power actually are leaders who have vision. Doesn't make them ideal, but you also can't simply assume none of them aren't motivated to do what's needed/right for the society, at least by their accounting of what's needed/right.

Direct extrinsic motivation.
The main goal of people in power is... wait for it... to remain in power. If you don't fix DNS and people can't watch their cat videos and tiktoks, you aren't going to be earning any popularity among your populace. If you have a superbacteria outbreak that kills a ton of people, you'll be somewhat less popular, though probably lack of cat videos is far more of a hit on popularity. This is especially true in representative democracy, where politicians literally have to face the risk of being elected out of office if people are unhappy enough. But ANY government, even tyrannical, tends to want to be more popular rather than less popular.
Also, in a competitive election environment, any issue you don't fix, is an opportunity for opposition candidates/parties to paint you in bad light and you risk losing election to them.

Indirect extrinsic motivation.
Even if you aren't worried about popularity, you are worried about power. DNS going down will screw up your economy and therefore both power of the country in general AND tax revenue. Supervirus will kill off a bunch of people, hose the economy etc...
In other words, generally, what's really bad for the populace, has at least some indirect reflection in being bad for the country's power. Which is a priority for any politician.



Your examples focus on potential, future problems, and for these, you are correct, the electorate is usually unaware of these and not particularly interested in them even if they become aware. Thus, the electorate is not good at evaluating these and they rarely play much role in voting. (More accurately, the human species as a whole isn’t all that great at it, and getting even halfway decent at it for many fields requires a great deal of education and training, that no one could possibly have for every field.)
However, the electorate is pretty good at noticing when problems have actually occurred and disrupt their lives. They’re also usually pretty interested in finding out why, and who is to blame. The electorate almost always wants someone to blame.
So that’s the (cynical) incentive: politicians want to keep their jobs. If something bad happens, they risk losing them. They can reduce that risk by preventing the bad thing from happening—so that is something they are incentivized to do.
(Of course, this is the very simplified version of things, where in reality politicians are people and have a great many motivations in addition to and beyond “keep my job,” and so may be inclined to pursue things even if they don’t have a significant impact on their likelihood of keeping their job. But those aren’t necessarily part of the “system” that seemed to be the thrust of the question.)

Its money and bureaucracy.
This is assuming a democratic system of government.
Money
It takes money to run the government. Money comes from businesses (even personal income tax and property tax comes from wages and profits of businesses of self-employed workers).
Things that are disastrous to business, therefore to money, will be eradicated or tried very hard to be eradicated. For example, denial of service attacks are bad for online businesses, therefore governments will be pressed by private businesses to do something about it. Same way, large pandemics are bad for businesses.
Also, politicians in a democratic system of government are either large businessmen themselves or are sponsored by large businessmen.
Bureaucracy
Politicians come and go, you will have this party ruling today, other party ruling next term, yet another party after that and so on with some repeats. What remains in position are bureaucrats. These are the people that actually run the government.
You see a president, prime minister or minister can just tell these bureaucrats his wishes which would be taken as general guideline only. The government officials know how to run the government and they do that whoever is at the top. By necessity they are given a lot of leeway in the how department. Its because the politicians who are the top don't know how to actually implement their policies.
The bureaucrats have interest in running the government departments smoothly. They have their prestige at stake and even if some official don't care about it it still increase work for him when problems come. You see these officials resist change because it result in uncertainty. Letting problems grow also create uncertainty. Nobody like a ticking time bomb near him especially when its uncertain when it will blow.
Summary
This all can be summarized by pointing you towards the second layer. You are seeing only politicians at work and neglecting the underlying cream that makes the wheel moves. Its this layer which keeps the politicians align.
In medieval monarchy in Europe it used to be feudal lords. They had both bureaucratic and judicial roles, in addition of military roles. They kept the kings align. When a king go too wild he tends to be removed.
In today's democratic system of government its the bureaucrats. In semi-democratic / partially dictatoral system of government (where military rules sometimes, democratic politician rule sometimes or there is one party rule which is strongly backed by military) add in military officials too. Judiciary keep itself out of this.
The second part of this second layer is large businessmen. Their job is to generate huge profits that combined makes the bulk of government income. These businessmen therefore have a leverage. Unlike government officials though, they are pro-change. Its because some changes create new business opportunities and these people are risk takers. They just try to avoid unplanned changes.

Governments are set up to govern. And in democracies we have representative democracy as direct democracy would be far too unwieldy and time consuming. What this means is that the average citizen does not need to be an expert in all the minutae of governance but they can judge the results of the governance: for example, has there been any outbreaks of disease, is there data safe on server farms. The press is a crucial part of this as they inform citizens of whefe things have gone wrong.
Democracy is so set up to incentivise the governments to govern well.
